# How do I fetch data from a public API on form submit using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, api

I am building a simple webpage where the user can enter a year in a text field and be presented with a list of F1 races for that year.

I am getting my data from this public API: http://ergast.com/mrd/ I need to achieve this in vanilla JS. I do not want to use jQuery.

So far I have tried the fetch method and I can console log:

```
fetch('http://ergast.com/api/f1/2020.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

This shows me all the races for the year 2020.

However I need the user to input the year, which then gets queried with the API and then the results should be displayed.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<form>
   <label>
      <span>Full name</span>
       <input type="text" id="test" placeholder="">
    </label>
    <button type="submit" id="form-submit">
       Button
    </button>
</form>
```

There are many similar questions already on SO but none that have been helpful for me.

*EDIT*

I also need to try and access the race results for any given year, Race results are nested within the array > data.MRData.RaceTable.Races.0.Results and I'm not sure how to access these values.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  <style>
     fieldset {
       margin: 10px;
     }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <label>
        <span>Year</span>
        <input value="2020" type="text" id="year" placeholder="type a year" />
      </label>
      <button type="submit" id="form-submit">
        Button
      </button>
    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>

    <script>
      const result = document.getElementById("result");
      document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const year = document.getElementById("year").value;
        fetch("http://ergast.com/api/f1/" + year + ".json")
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
            result.innerHTML = `<b>results for ${year}</b>`;
            data.MRData.RaceTable.Races.forEach((race) => {
              result.innerHTML += `
<fieldset>
  <h4> ${race.raceName} </h4>
  <a target="_blank" href="${race.Circuit.url}"> ${race.Circuit.circuitName} </a>
  <p> ${race.date} - ${race.Circuit.Location.country} </p>
</fieldset>`
            });
          });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Venom X - How would the results be displayed in a HTML div?

Comment: How do you want the data to be presented to the visitor?

Comment: In a list would work I think.

Comment: i edited the comment you can see now how it can be displayed in the html.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach. You will need to think about how you want to display the data though. Many paragraphs isn't very user friendly.

```js
let body = document.querySelector('body');

document.querySelector("form").addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  const year = document.getElementById('year').value;
  e.preventDefault();
  fetch(`https://ergast.com/api/f1/${year}.json`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      (data.MRData.RaceTable.Races).forEach(races => {
        for(race in races) {
          let para = document.createElement('p');
          para.innerText = races[race];
          body.appendChild(para);
        }
      })
    })
  })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <label>
       <span>Year</span>
        <input type="text" id="year" placeholder="">
     </label>
     <button type="submit" id="form-submit">
        Button
     </button>
  </form>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The **API URL is just a string**, therefore the easiest way would be adding a button to your form and put the API call in **`onclick()`** event attribute of button.

```html
<form>
   <label>
      <span>Full name</span>
       <input type="text" id="test">
    </label>
    <button id="form-submit" onclick="apiFetcher()">
       Fetch!
    </button>
</form>
<p id="result"></>
```

And the JS function:

```js
function apiFetcher()
{
    var year = document.getElementById("test").value;
 
   fetch("http://ergast.com/api/f1/" + year + ".json")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => document.getElementById("result").innerText = data);
}
```

> Note that there are about or more than 10 ways to get an `input` element's value but as for calling the API **you have to concatenate the user inputted year to rest of the URL** no matter how you get the value.
> By not using `<button type="submit">` but a simple `<button>` you remove the need to handle default event.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// dom element references
const myBtn = document.getElementById("form-submit")
const myInput = document.getElementById("test")



myBtn.addEventListener("click", (event)=>{
event.preventDefault()

const text = myInput.value;

myInput.value=""

fetch(`http://ergast.com/api/f1/${text}.json`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
  console.log(data)
  document.getElementById("data-here").innerText= data.MRData.RaceTable.Races[0].Circuit.Location.country;
  });
})
```

```html
<form>
   <label>
      <span>Year</span>
       <input min="1980" max="2022" type="number" id="test" placeholder="" value="2020">
    </label>
    <button type="submit" id="form-submit">
       Button
    </button>
</form>

<div id="data-here"></div>
```